# How to find number of squares in a chess board

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Problem :

An $ n\times n$ chess board is a square of side $n$ units which has been sub-divided into $n^2$ unit squares by equally spaced straight lines parallel to the sides. Find the total number of squares of all sizes on an $n \times n$  chess board.

I have been trying to study the pattern of this how to derive the following : 
Answer : $1^2+2^2+\dots+n^2$

Please help .. thanks...

Comment: For the record, you may find this simpler:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = n(n+1)(2n+1)/6.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of $1 \times 1$ squares is $n^2$ because there are $n^2$ places to put the upper left corner.  The grid is $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ (including the edges) but you can't use the bottom edge or the right edge.  For a $2 \times 2$ square, the upper left corner can be in $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ locations, a $3 \times 3$ square can have the upper left corner in $(n-2) \times (n-2)$ locations $\dots$

Added:  Let us take an $5 \times 5$ board to be specific and number the locations from $(0,0)$ in the upper left to $(5,5)$ in the lower right.  There are $5^2 \  1 \times 1$ squares.  Each one can have its upper left corner in positions $(0,0)$ through $(4,4)$.  There are $4^2 \ 2 \times 2$ squares, because the upper left corner can be $(0,0)$ through $(3,3)$, $3^2 \ 3 \times 3$ squares, because the upper left corner can be $(0,0)$ through $(2,2)$, on to $1^2 \ 5 \times 5$ square, because it has only one location it can fit.  This gives a total number of squares of $5^2+4^2+3^2+2^2+1^2$ as desired.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for the hint, I really tried to understand your method, but didn't actually got it completely, and understanding your method leads me to find the pattern of the square when number of lines increases i.e. when it is $1 \times 1 = 1^2 + 2^2 = 5 ; $.when it is $ 2 \times 2 $ square this gives $1^2 +2^2+3^2$ squares and when it is $3 \times 3$ it will give you $1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2$ squares...I thinks  this is correct .. thanks once again